# Question on connected metric spaces and continous functions

Tags: continuity, connectedness

This question came up in some sample questions my teacher sent for an upcoming test.
I tried the part a with the theorem that the preimage of a non constant function would not be connected but I got the result for closed sets and the definition of connectedness talks of open sets.

For part b, I am pretty sure that by taking cases for an element being in A, B and then A ∩ B and proving the result for them separately is the way to go.

Show that a metric space (M, d) is connected iff every continuous function
f : M → {±1} is a constant function.

(b) Let (M, d) be a metric space. Let A and B be two connected subsets of M such that A ∩ B
is nonempty. Then A ∪ B is connected.

Thanks for the help (I desperately need some in real analysis)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. A continuous function maps a connected set to a connected set.

Comment: So we can use this to say that if M is connected, a continuous function from M to {±1} will have a connected range and can only have 1 value from then and hence is constant. But how do you go about that if every function from M to {±1} is a constant function, M is connected? Thanks again

Comment: Take the preimage of the disconnected open sets $B(\pm1,{1 \over 3})$.

Comment: I am sorry but could you explain that a bit more? How would that help?